# Embed laravel application version using git describe

Tags: git, version, laravel-5

I want to find an elegant way to embed the output of:

```
git describe --long > app\version.tmp
```

to my Laravel 5 application. note that i dont need a way to automate the command.

I thought of redirecting the output to a file and then read it in a custom config file in Laravel. But it doesnt feel elegant to me.

Any other suggestions?

Note 1:

This is what i am thinking to use:

```
<?php

return [

    'version' => preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9.\-]/', '',file_get_contents(app_path() . '\version.tmp')),
];
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `exec()`, perhaps? http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: No i dont want to automate the git command. I have this covered.I just need to be able to use it in my laravel app

Comment: I meant that you could get the output through exec() on-the-fly, but it sounds like you've thought of that already. If you already have the file created, I'd probably just create a helper function or method to retrieve it. But it kinda boils down to preference rather than best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my application, I have an "About" dialog that the user can access via a menu. The "About" dialog displays the current version number and the short git commit hash.

I store my version information in my `.env` file in two values: `APP_VERSION` and `APP_HASH`. These values are rendered into the HTML for the dialog.

I update these values via a short BASH script (see below). I have a build process which prepares the application for release (rebuilds CSS from less, minimizes my CSS & JS, copies the production `.env` file, and a few other things),  so I execute this script whenever I am preparing to release an update to the application.

Here's the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# store the production .env file outside my development environment. It will
# be copied when I build the application
#
PRODUCTION=/path/to/production/.env

# store the local (development) .env file in the development environment
# 
LOCAL=./.env

# get the git hash value
# 
CURRENT_GIT_HASH=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)

# get the new version number from the command line
# 
NEW_VERSION="$1"

# get the old version number from the production .env file
# 
OLD_VERSION=$(grep -P "^APP_VERSION=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$" "$PRODUCTION" | grep -Po "([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)")

echo "Current version = $OLD_VERSION"

# check to see if the version number is valid
# 
CHECK=$(echo "$NEW_VERSION" | grep -P "^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$")

# do we have a new version number? if so, check to see if it's changed
# 
if [ -n "$NEW_VERSION" ]; then

    # do we have a valid version number? if not, let the user know
    # 
    if [ -z "$CHECK" ]; then
        echo "Invalid version number: $NEW_VERSION"
    else
        echo "Bumping version to $NEW_VERSION ($CURRENT_GIT_HASH)"

        # update the version number
        #
        sed -ri "s/APP_VERSION=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/APP_VERSION=$NEW_VERSION/" "$PRODUCTION"
        sed -ri "s/APP_VERSION=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/APP_VERSION=$NEW_VERSION/" "$LOCAL"

        # update the version number
        #
        sed -ri "s/APP_HASH=[0-9a-f]+/APP_HASH=$CURRENT_GIT_HASH/" "$PRODUCTION"
        sed -ri "s/APP_HASH=[0-9a-f]+/APP_HASH=$CURRENT_GIT_HASH/" "$LOCAL"

        # tag the current commit with the version number
        #
        git tag -a "bump-$NEW_VERSION" -m "bump version from $OLD_VERSION to $NEW_VERSION"
    fi
fi
```

This might be a little more complicated than what you're doing, but it has the benefit that the version # & hash are available through the standard `env()` helper function.

Comment: I should mention that this also has the benefit of not requiring you to parse another file every time a page loads. The version/git commit don't change that often (at least in production), so for me, generating these values when I'm building a release makes sense.

Comment: Very Nice!! Are you using GULP for the build process you describe?

Comment: Yes, gulp. I don't use Laravel's new elixir system simply because this is a Laravel 4 application which was upgrade to Laravel 5 & I didn't want to convert my gulpfile. If I were starting from scratch, I would probably go with elixir. But the build process is more than that - my application runs in a set of [Docker](http://docker.com) containers and the build process actually builds those containers & pushes them to a local repository so I can pull them onto the production server & run them.

Answer (score 0):

In the same philosophy as Kryten 's answer, i am putting here what i did using powershell:

```
function setConfigValue( $file, $key, $value ) {
    $content = Get-Content $file
    if ( $content -match "^$key\s*=" ) {
        $content -replace "^$key\s*=.*", "$key=$value" |
        Set-Content $file     
    } else {
        Add-Content $file "$key=$value"
    }
}

$ver = &"git" describe --long | Out-String

setConfigValue ".\.env" "APP_VERSION" $ver
```